# Prolog generator stuck infinitely trying THE SAME OBJECT over and over?

Tags: list, prolog

I am really stuck on a problem in Prolog. I am trying to make a generator "gen_lists_of_pairs(V, L)", which, given a list of natural numbers V, generates all possible lists containing two-element lists, such that their elements are unique and every element is in the form [A, B] where A and B are members of V and A < B. However, the generator seems to get stuck in an infinite loop trying the same thing over and over. I am new to prolog and I have had generators that are stuck attempting infinite possibilities, but I cannot fathom why in the world prolog gets stuck here..

This is my code:

```
ascending([_]).
ascending([A, B|L]) :- A < B, ascending([B|L]).

gen_list_of_pairs(_, []).

gen_list_of_pairs(V, [[X,Y]|L]) :-
    gen_list_of_pairs(V, L),
    member(X, V),
    member(Y, V),
    ascending([X, Y]),
    not((member([X, Y], L))).
```

And this is the debug trace when calling "gen_list_of_pairs([1], X).":

```
Call:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7086)
 Exit:gen_list_of_pairs([1], [])
X = []
 Redo:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7086)
 Call:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7902)
 Exit:gen_list_of_pairs([1], [])
 Call:lists:member(_7906, [1])
 Exit:lists:member(1, [1])
 Call:lists:member(_7912, [1])
 Exit:lists:member(1, [1])
 Call:ascending([1, 1])
 Call:1<1
 Fail:1<1
 Fail:ascending([1, 1])
 Redo:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7902)
 Call:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7920)
 Exit:gen_list_of_pairs([1], [])
 Call:lists:member(_7924, [1])
 Exit:lists:member(1, [1])
 Call:lists:member(_7930, [1])
 Exit:lists:member(1, [1])
 Call:ascending([1, 1])
 Call:1<1
 Fail:1<1
 Fail:ascending([1, 1])
 Redo:gen_list_of_pairs([1], _7920)
 ...
```

As you can see, after outputting "X = []", prolog gets stuck in an infinite loop, trying the pair [1,1] over and over and over, even though as far as my scarce knowledge goes, it should either attempt something else or stop the query after failing an attempt... I cannot whatsoever figure this out and am growing increasingly frustrated. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: It is also notable that for larger lists it generates all the objects correctly, however at the end continues trying to generate the same object over and over instead of finishing the query and returning false..

Answer (score 0):

There is too much recursion in there. Especially as you are recursing "on the left"

```
gen_list_of_pairs(V, [[X,Y]|L]) :-
    gen_list_of_pairs(V, L), ...
```

With the second argument uninstantiated, this goes off to infinity, no matter what comes afterwards:

```
gen_list_of_pairs(V, [[X,Y]|L]) :-
    gen_list_of_pairs(V, L),false.
```

Then:

```
?- gen_list_of_pairs([1,2,3],X).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
```

... because there is no stopping criterium. We just pile on `[X,Y]` to an ever-lengthening list.

It's better to start afresh.

In fact, the task of appending to the "Bag of Solution" is being taken care of by [`bagof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3) and [`setof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3).

We just need to generate new pairs, backtrackably, from `V`:

```
gimme_another_pair(V,[X,Y]) :-
   member(X,V),
   member(Y,V),
   X < Y.
```

Then

```
?- gimme_another_pair([1,2,3],P).
P = [1, 2] ;
P = [1, 3] ;
P = [2, 3] ;
false.
```

And so:

```
gen_list_of_pairs(V, Result) :- setof(P,gimme_another_pair(V,P),Result).
```

And so:

```
?- gen_list_of_pairs([1,2,3],X).
X = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]].
```